# The values of the universe’s scale factor at the different eras of the universe’s evolution

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, universe, dark-energy

I’m reading this paper:

[A unified geometric description of the Universe....](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269322000739)

In Fig. (1) they show the different values of the universe’s scale factor at the different eras of the universe’s time evolution

[image]

They say the inflationary era started at $ln~a/a_0=-70$, take $a_0=1$, then the inflationary era started at  $a=e^{-70}= 4*10^{-31}$, then ended at $a=e^{-35}= 6.3*10^{-16}$. Then there is some era from $a=e^{-35}$ to around $a=e^{-6}$. Then another era from  $a=e^{-6}$ where they say CMB has been occurred.

First what is this white era between $a=e^{-35}$ to around $a=e^{-6}$, and the blue era from $a=e^{-6} $ to now days, what does it mean this blue era  when CMB ( the cosmological microwave background ) occurs, and which era the white or the blue when the current late time acceleration started?

How can we apply these values on $\Lambda$CDM? Or how did they assign these value of $a$?

Here is the curve of the scale factor versus time according to $\Lambda$CDM, the time is given by Gyr= $10^9$ year, and the vertical grideline at the current universe age $t_0 = 13.842 ~ Gyr = 1.384 * 10^{10}$ year.

[image]

Here is the acceleration of the scale factor versus time, the beginning of the current late time acceleration happens at $\ddot{a}=0$, which is at $t \sim 7.7$, and $a(t) \sim 
0.6$. Where is this on the paper’s first graph?

[image]

About inflation it happens when the slow roll parameter $- \frac{\dot{H}}{H^2} < 1$, which occurs here around $t=9$

[image]

Now adding a grideline at $t=9$ for $a(t)$ curve, this means the inflatory epoch is just before the current universe age, i,e. there is no the white era as in the paper which separates inflation era from near the current era?

[image]

It gets worse in the $\ddot{a}(t)$ curve, because it means the inflation happened after the beginning of the current time acceleration!!

[image]

The curves of $\Lambda$CDM from:
[FLRW.functions](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/FLRW.functions.html)

Any help to is appreciated!

Comment: The curves on my site that you have linked are without inflation, if you have inflation you have to model the $\rm H$ somewhat like $\rm H=Min[H_0 \sqrt{\Omega_r/a^4+\Omega_m/a^3+\Omega_{\Lambda}}, \ H_i]$ with the $\rm H_i$ for the constant inflationary Hubble parameter (which doesn't tell much about the derivatives at the crossing from inflation to expansion since it's just an approximation, if your reference gives a more specific function for the $\rm H$ use that). On a log/log-plot you will also see more than on a linear one since the era in question is much less than a pixel on the latter

Comment: Dr. phy wrote: *"In Fig. (1) they show the different values of the universe’s scale factor at the different eras of the universe’s time evolution"* - that is wrong, they show a log/log-plot of $\rm H/H_0$, not $\rm a$, and that as a function of the scale factor $\rm a/a_0=a$, not time $\rm t$. Something similar, just for the reciprocal $\rm c/H$ is at https://lcdm.yukterez.net/curvature.radius.flrw.inflation.html

Comment: @Yukterez. Thanks for the link. I think in this Mathematica file, you take a= time ? Let's talk about the blue curve, I think it shows that at the beginning of the inflation era around $10^{-31}$ sec, the Hubble radius was around $10^{-24}$ m, then at inflation it increases till $10^{28}$ m, it's value currently at $a $ or $t \sim 10^{10}$ year ( the vertical grideline  is before $10^{9}$ may be you take t-axis by sec, or if this is the dimensionless $a $, you consider some relation between $a$ and  $t$.

Comment: The minimum value you consider at H calculation is $ 3 * 10^{36}$ $sec^{-1}$, 
that gives Hubble radius by around $r= 10^{26}$ m.


If what I understand till now is correct, may I ask, the current value of the Hubble parameter H0 $ \sim 10^{-18} ~ sec^{-1}$, so that r0  equals $c/H0 = 3*10^{26}$m? 

Another thing is the Min value you take for H, is it the value that gives the current value of the Hubble radius? Or is it the value of H at inflation?

Comment: Dr. phy asked: *"I think in this Mathematica file, you take a= time ?"* - No, you can't do that, *a* is a function of *t*; in the radiation dominated era *a=√[2·H₀·t·√(Ωr)]* for example, the other eras are also in the  [link](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/FLRW.functions.html) you linked in your question, and at the bottom of the link is how you integrate numerically for an arbitrary *a(t)*, but note that *a* can't start at zero if you begin with inflation, the scale factor can be arbitrary small then but not zero since *a∝ eᴴᵗ* during inflation, which never gets 0.