# Explaining inflation in $\Lambda$CDM

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation

When plotting the acceleration of the scale factor according to $\Lambda$CDM, it does not show any inflationary behavior ($a'' > 0$) in early times. Does this mean the inflation is not described in  $\Lambda$CDM? and we need new models beyond the general relativity so that solving the modified Friedmann equations includes inflation?

Here are the plots, according to [Lambda-CDM scale factor](https://f.yukterez.net/einstein.equations/files/FLRW.functions.html)

[image]

Or for early times

[image]

Comment: You already asked that here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/713098/24093 
 In my first comment I told you how to adjust for inflation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Lambda$CDM is a model primarily intended to describe the universe only after its earliest moments. By "after earliest moments" I mean, roughly, after the Planck era and
after a rapid inflationary period if there was one.
To describe the earliest moments (i.e. inflation or bounce or whatever) one might propose either a $\Lambda$CDM-like model which includes large changes in the parameters as a function of time, or one might try some other model.